# Is it possible to grab a screenshot from the AppleWatch?

Tags: ios, apple-watch

Just wondering.. The watch can remotely control the iOS camera, and keep it's photos. I was hoping their would be a similar capability re screen images.

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's a way to take a screenshot on the Apple Watch, and it's exactly what you'd expect it to be if you're familiar with the iPhone's screenshot function.

1. Press and hold the Digital Crown.
2. Immediately press and release the side button.
3. Release the Digital Crown.

You should see the screen flash and get some haptic feedback acknowledging it, and then the screenshot should show up in Camera Roll. Good luck!

[Source](http://www.imore.com/how-take-screenshot-apple-watch)